# Hpricot search how to

Tags: ruby, xpath, hpricot

I would like to do a search in a webpage if I have result than I need a property.
Here is the webpage: [link text](http://mashable.com/2010/08/06/expedition-titanic)

I am interested if, the header the  meta has the **property** with value "og:title" ot nor, if has I want the **content** value

If we look at the source of the page, it has a potion of:

```
<meta
property="og:title" content="Explore the Titanic Wreck Site via Social Media [EXCLUSIVE]" />
```

so I want a true result for og:title query and a Explore the Titanic Wreck Site via Social Media [EXCLUSIVE] value for next search, how to do it properly

`search("/html/head/meta[(@property='og:title']")` doesn't return what I want.

any suggestion?

Comment: I'd recommend switching to [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org). It's easy to use, like Hpricot, but in my experience it's a lot more stable.

Comment: @user529543: From [this](http://hpricot.com/demonstrations) documentation, it doesn't look like Hpricot is a standar complain XPath engine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
/html/head/meta[@property='og:title']/@content
```

Comment: +1 for the correct answer. Probably it's worth mentioning how to register namespaces.

Comment: Might want to check that answer. I get nothing when I use Hpricot: `>> (doc % "/html/head/meta[@property='og:title']/@content") #=> nil`
and `>> (doc / "/html/head/meta[@property='og:title']/@content") #=> #<Hpricot::Elements[]>`

Comment: @Greg: This is a correct XPath expression. The page is served as text/html besides that it looks like a transitional XHTML (not wellformed because some not escaped `&`...), so I assume there is some special parsing involve that let me wander about namespace handling as point out by @Dimitre

Comment: The HTML is full of errors, but it's a great example of real-world HTML in the wilds. The XPath looks correct to me too, but Hpricot isn't returning a value, which was one of my contentions with it. Without `/@content` Hpricot finds the node. Nokogiri finds the node with or without `/@content` which reinforces my preference for it.

Comment: @Greg: From documentation already linked, it looks like Hpricot is not a standar complain XPath engine.

Comment: @Alejandro, I've heard that too. It's like 90% useful but it's those cases that break that drive me nuts when I think it's in my code and turns out to be the underlying library. That's what I ran into just before I switched to Nokogiri; I was under a tight deadline and found a fatal bug in Hpricot parsing some wild HTML. Why the Lucky Stiff had just disappeared, trying to remove Hpricot in the process, so I talked to Aaron Patterson about the bug and HTML and gave Nokogiri a try. I've been happy I did.

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath has an error in it, plus is too restrictive:

```
search("/html/head/meta[(@property='og:title']")
```

should be:

```
search("/html/head/meta[@property='og:title']")
```

to fix the error. I'd simplify it to:

```
search("//meta[@property='og:title']")
```

Also, it's not quite clear what you want to do. Do you want to find

```
<meta 
  property="og:title" 
  content="Explore the Titanic Wreck Site via Social Media [EXCLUSIVE]" 
 />
```

and extract the `content` parameter? Or do you want to locate the tag, confirm it contains both the `"og:title"` property tag and the `"Explore the Titanic Wreck Site via Social Media [EXCLUSIVE]"` content, and then do further processing?

That said, often it's simpler to use CSS accessors instead of XPath. I prefer using Nokogiri, which has both XPath and CSS selectors; I'm using CSS below:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://mashable.com/2010/08/06/expedition-titanic'))
(doc % 'meta[property="og:title"]')
=> #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x8084ee48 name="meta" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x8084ed58 name="property" value="og:title">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x8084ed1c name="content" value="Explore the Titanic Wreck Site via Social Media [EXCLUSIVE]">]>
```

Nokogiri and Hpricot support the `/` and `%` shorthand for `search` and `at` respectively. "Search" returns an array of all matches, and "at" returns only the first match. So, the example above gets the first node using the CSS, showing this is the right track. I'm not sure how to use CSS to match two parameters in the same tag, so I'll go after *all* `<meta>` tags with `property="og:title"`, then filter based on the `content=` parameter:

```
(doc / 'meta[property="og:title"]').select{ |n| n['content'][/titanic wreck site/i] }
=> [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x8084ee48 name="meta" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x8084ed58 name="property" value="og:title">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x8084ed1c name="content" value="Explore the Titanic Wreck Site via Social Media [EXCLUSIVE]">]>]
```

At that point we've got the right node in the returned array, so you can extract whatever you want, or dive into its children and sack and pillage. To do that you'll want to use `.first` or `[0]` to get at the actual node for further processing:

```
(doc / 'meta[property="og:title"]').select{ |n| n['content'][/titanic wreck site/i] }.first
```

---

Update based on OP's response, using Nokogiri still:

```
>> meta = (doc % 'meta[@property="og:title"]')['content']
>> meta #=> "Explore the Titanic Wreck Site via Social Media [EXCLUSIVE]"
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for answers.
When I posted my question I couldn't realize I have a mistake in the search. It was Friday evening...

The correct search is

```
elements = @doc.search("/html/head/meta[@property='og:title']")
```

- it is removed a `(` character from expression before @property

This give the:

```
elements = <meta property="og:title" content="Explore the Titanic Wreck Site via Social Media [EXCLUSIVE]" />
```

result.
Than I am checking if I have something or not, if I have, than I need the content value

```
if elements.nil?
   puts 'not found'
  elsif elements.size > 0
    puts "Found one, og:title = #{elements}" 
    content = elements.attr("content");
    puts content # this will display the content ( it will be processed)
  else
    ... can come here the flow control? - theoretically yes, but in practice?
  end
```

Comment: Instead of adding your updates as answers please append them to your original question. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the flow will go to the `else` statement if the initial `if` or following `elsif` don't match their condition. In your example `elements` would not be nil and would be empty.